# Allow contract to create transactions on my behalf

Tags: transactions

Is there any way to allow a contract to execute any transaction (sending assets or interacting with another contract) on my behalf ?

If it's not possible with a native ETH account, would a Gnosis multisig help ?

Comment: It is not possible for a contract to impersonate an external owned account because the EVM lack an opcode to achieve that. Multisig contracts usually have the capability to perform any operation possible, transfer ether, call other contracts, etc. I'm not sure about newer Gnosis versions, but old version have that capability.

Answer (score 0):

You can emit an event in your smart contract when you want your address do something, and listen for this event in a js script that will execute the transaction you want from your address when the specific contract event is received.